# Why doesn't Java have setMessage in Exception/Throwable classes?

Tags: java, exception

I am not able to understand why Java doesn't allow to change exception message of an exception of type Exception (or its superclass Throwable) once it has been created. It allows to change the stackTrace using setStackTrace but not the message.

The use case I have seems genuine to me and would appreciate some alternative.

**Use case**

I have a controller service X that calls let's say 10 other dependent services. To make debugging easy, if a dependent service throws some exception we want to surface some identifiers from service X to its upstream to identify the failed request easily. For this we have requestId which we create and set for each dependency.

Now to avoid duplication across all dependent services and simplify code, we can create a common interceptor that allows us to do some work before and after each call. Something like -

```
// do some work

requestId = getRequestId(); // create or somehow get requestId
dependentService.setRequestId(requestId);

try {
  dependentService.call();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.setMessage(e.getMessage() + ... + requestId);
  throw e;
}

//do some work
```

But Java doesn't allow us to set message. At the same time, we want to preserve the exception and its type (which could be any of the custom types defined by dependent services), so I don't want to do something like `throw new Exception(e.getMessage() + ...)`

Comment: You could simply use the [`Exception​(Throwable cause)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Throwable)) or [Exception​(String message, Throwable cause)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)) constructors

Comment: @MadProgrammer That would change the type of exception, though. "we want to preserve the exception and its type (which could be any of the custom types defined by dependent services)"

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but the requirement doesn't make sense (to me) and the suggested cause of action is the "normal" way to handle the situation. *"I don't want to"* isn't really good enough explanation for why they "need" this specific requirement

Comment: Create a new Exception by reflection: `throw e.getClass().getConstructor(String.class,Throwable.class).newInstance(e.getMessage() + ... + requestId,e)`.

Comment: @PeterMmm when reflection is the answer, chances are you're asking the wrong question ;)

Comment: We still want to have custom handling for various exception types thrown by dependencies. I think by going with `Exception(message, cause)' will make the code messy as outside the interceptor the business logic that calls the dependency would have to first catch Exception, then query various types with e.getCause() and then what if it doesn't want to handle certain types but rethrow them(to be handled by some other upstream function),then it would have to throw Exception and same thing would have to be done by upstream functions. I believe it would be much easier if Java allowed to set message

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right, only my 2ct.

Comment: If this is for debugging, it is probably a very workable solution to not mess with the exception, but have your interceptor just log the exception with its added request context information and then rethrow it unchanged.

Comment: @user11981729 saying "it would be easier if..." doesn't get you anywhere if that thing simply isn't possible.

Comment: It's a great question.  I hit this today with a long throwable message originating from a library that I don't control that overflowed my log handler message capacity (32k).  I'd like to truncate all my logged exception messages so I never get this problem, but otherwise leave the exceptions unchanged.  A setMessage() would have been nice.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *really* what it's meant for, but you could attach another exception with `addSuppressed`:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.addSuppressed(new ExtraInfoException(...));
  throw e;
}
```

where `...` contains the extra info you want to include.

The advantage of this over adding to the exception message is that you can define your `ExtraInfoException` so that it has the info you want in fields, rather than having to parse it back out of the exception message.

With that said, a more idiomatic way to attach more exception info it would be:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new ExtraInfoException(e, ...);
}
```

which has exactly the same advantage of allowing you to return structured information, with the additional advantage that you can catch `ExtraInfoException` directly, rather than catching `Exception` and then hunting for the extra info reflectively.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't Java have setMessage in Exception/Throwable classes?

The answer to your question is that they (the library designers) did not think that changing a message on an exception was a useful thing to do.

To a large degree<sup>1</sup>, the designers have taken the view that they shouldn't design the APIs to directly support all possible use-cases ... including the obscure ones that almost nobody will encounter.  Like your one<sup>2</sup>.

And in your case, there are other ways to achieve what you are trying to do; see the other answers.

I did a quick search of the Java bugs database to see if someone else had put in an RFE to request a `setMessage` method for `Throwable` or `Exception`. I couldn't find anything.  If your requirement was even slightly common, there would probably be an RFE with an explanation of why it was declined.

---

<sup>1 -  Obviously, there are exceptions to this, but that is beside the point.</sup>

<sup>2 - Obviously you would disagree that your use-case is obscure, but that that is *also* beside the point.  The question is why they haven't implemented this, not whether they were wrong.  (Asking / debating whether they were wrong is off-topic, because it is a matter of opinion.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Resetting a message it's some kind of rewriting the history. You have a `catch` block when you catch exception and handle them. If you need to throw an exception during the handling, it's a different problem and an exception should be different.

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
 // here we have SomeException and we want to handle it.
 // if we can't we throw a new one, because we have a problem with handling.
 // if the handling problem cause is SomeException we put it at the cause.
 throw new AnotherException("with some message", e);
}
```

And in the stacks trace we will see that we have `AnotherException` because of `SomeException` which gives us information about the root of problem.

Comment: Whilst I agree that rewriting history is bad, the Throwable class lets you [replace the stack trace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#setStackTrace(java.lang.StackTraceElement[])), which is a far more nefarious way to rewrite history.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply throw new instance like this:

```
try {
...
} catch(Exception ex) {
   throw new Exception ("new message", ex);
}
```

Comment: If you go that way (which is probably the only reasonable way), you can make it `new ServiceException(requestId, serviceName, ex)`, so that you can have `getCause()` to get to the original exception (with its type) and `getRequestId()` as well.

Comment: Don't use `e.getCause()` as the cause. This hides where `e` was actually thrown from. Use `e`.